# Passport Question regarding J1 visa in the US

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passport-renewals, j1-visas

I am going to start my job as a residency physician soon in US. For that I have to apply for an exchange visitor J1 visa. My passport expires exactly around the time of my intended stay. My country (Afghanistan) is not included in the exempted countries for the 6 months rule (meaning my passport should be valid 6 months beyond my intended stay). In the current situations of covid-19, it would be difficult to renew passport. Will it be okay to apply for an exchange visitor J1 visa with my existing passport keeping in mind I can easily get a new passport in the US?

Comment: This question deals with a long-term international move for employment. It therefore belongs instead on https://expatriates.stackexchange.com. I voted to close.

Comment: As @DavidSupportsMonica says, your question belongs on Expatriates, but it's unclear. Is your passport going to expire soon after you arrive or around when your stay will be over?

Comment: The Afghani embassies in the US are currently closed so it's not guaranteed that it will be easier to renew your passport in the US.

Comment: My passport will expire arount the time my intended stay in the United States ends which is 1 year.

Answer (score 5):

Your passport just needs to be valid for at least 6 months at the time you plan to enter the US. They will issue you a visa as long as your planned date of entry is at least 6 months before the expiration date of your passport.

The rule about needing to have a passport valid for at least 6 months beyond the period of stay basically means that the immigration officer at entry will not put on your I-94 an admit-until date that is later than 6 months before your passport expires. However, J1 are usually admitted for "D/S" on their I-94, not a date. So that rule doesn't apply to you, other than needing to have a passport valid for at least 6 months when you enter.